# Issue with setting wd

Tags: r, function, directory, rstudio, fread

Hey everyone having some trouble executing this code. Here is what my boss told me to do, having such a remedial issue. PLease advice.

```
require(data.table)
require(MASS)

dat = fread("~/OneDrive - SUNY Upstate Medical University/bin/projects/rdoc/brett_project_igt/WGCNA_moduleEigengenes_SamplePhenotype.txt")
#working on setting the right directory
#C:\Users\brett\OneDrive\Desktop\Lab\brett_project_igt
dat = fread("~/Users/brett/OneDrive/Desktop/Lab/WGCNA_moduleEigengenes_SamplePhenotype.txt")

hist(dat$IGT_total_net)
hist(dat$IGT_total_lat)

# linear model
fit = lm(IGT_total_net  ~ Age + Gender + SV1 + race + RIN + ME36, data = dat)
summary(fit)

# negative binomial model
fit = glm.nb(IGT_total_lat ~ Age + Gender + SV1 + race + RIN + ME36, data = dat)
summary(fit)
```

Here is my most current error message, some of the previous issues have been not having the right wd, then also having issues with fread function. Thanks in advance.

```
Error in fread("C:/Users/brett/AppData/Local/Packages/Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe/TempState/Downloads") : 
  File 'C:/Users/brett/AppData/Local/Packages/Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe/TempState/Downloads' is a directory. Not yet implemented.
```

Comment: FYI, https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting. "Readability" of a question can make a difference for many people (me included), and I suggest that unformatted code, interpreted into HTML, is very distracting.

Comment: The error message mentions `.../Downloads/`, which neither of your calls to `fread` in your code uses. Especially when you use absolute paths in your reads, current working directory has little if any impact.